# Firebase Authentication force get claims updated in signin

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, ngrx-effects

In my application when registering a new user I need to ensure that before navigating to a route it gets a value that I need inside of the `claims` when calling the `getIdTokenResult(true)` method.

I am passing the `forceRefresh` parameter to true, but I can not get the **customClaims** updated, I need to logout the user and log in to get the updated data.

I need to ensure that whenever the user registers, he waits for the return of a token with updated claims before setting the state and navigating to the main screen.

```
private _setUserControlAccess = firebase.functions()
    .httpsCallable('setUserControlAccess')

@Effect()
signin$: Observable<Action> = this._actions.pipe(
    ofType(authActions.SIGNIN),
    map((action: authActions.Signin) => action.payload),
    switchMap(user => {

        this._matSnackbar.open('Efetuando o registro...', '', {
            horizontalPosition: this._horizontalPosition,
            verticalPosition: this._verticalPosition,
        });

        return from(this._angularFireAuth.auth
            .createUserAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)).pipe(
                switchMap(response => this._setUserConfigurations(response, user)),
                //filter() Add filter here? to check token.claims.firestoreCollection exists?
                map(([_, token, user]) => {
                    const authStateObject = this._getAuthStateObject(token, user);

                    // before setting the state, I need to ensure that token.claims is updated.
                    return new authActions.Authenticated(authStateObject);
                }),
                tap(() => this._router.navigate([''])),
                catchError((error) => of(new authActions.AuthError({ error: error })))
            )
    })
)


private _setUserConfigurations(
    response: firebase.auth.UserCredential,
    user: any
) {
    return forkJoin([
        from(response.user.updateProfile({
            displayName: user.nome.trim(),
            photoURL: 'assets/images/avatars/profile.jpg'
        })),
        from(response.user.getIdTokenResult(true)),
        from(of(response.user)),
        from(this._setUserControlAccess({
            firestoreCollection: response.user.uid,
            admin: true,
            assinante: true,
            profissional: true,
            email: response.user.email
        }))
    ]);
}

private _getAuthStateObject(
    token: firebase.auth.IdTokenResult,
    user: firebase.User
) {
    const authStateObject = {
        admin: token.claims.admin,
        profissional: token.claims.profissional,
        assinante: token.claims.assinante,
        firestoreCollection: token.claims.firestoreCollection,
        user: user
    }

    return authStateObject;
}
```

**In Cloud Functions:**

```
export const setUserControlAccess = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        const customUserClaims = {
            admin: data.admin,
            assinante: data.assinante,
            profissional: data.profissional,
            firestoreCollection: data.firestoreCollection
        };

        const user = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email);
        await authentication.setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, customUserClaims);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return error;
    }
});
```